# Sound constantly disappears in MacBook Pro 2020 (Intel)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, sound-volume

After the latest update to **Ventura 13.5.2**, I have started experiencing issues with sound. Initially, the audio works for a few seconds after a reboot. However, after playing the very first music or video, the sound disappears.

> For example, when I play a video in VLC, it has sound, but if I switch to another video or audio, the sound disappears. Even playing a YouTube video in the browser doesn't have sound.

To temporarily resolve this issue, I have to **force quit** the **coreaudiod** process, but this solution only works for a few minutes, and then the sound disappears again.

I have tried several solutions including,

- NVRAM reset and SMC reset, but all of them provide only temporary relief, as the audio works for a while before encountering the same issue.

I also posted this in [Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255130696), but nothing helped.

Comment: Do you have any additional (non-standard) audio outputs, or audio drivers? Are you using the built-in speakers? Does the sound only disappear when you switch to another app/tab? Do you have any audio apps like Logic, Cubase open?

Comment: No I have only my monitor connected via the HDMI, I tried even without that as well. Yes the problem is when I switch the Apps the sound dissappears, I have to quite coreaudiod multiple times to get the sound back. I dont have any audio apps except VLC and Spotify

Comment: `@Safnaj` Since you mentioned that the **Switching Apps** causes the issue, I suspect that any other audio apps crash the `Core Audio Daemon` service, Try Uninstalling / Updating **VLC** / **Spotify** Kind of apps.

Comment: @BadPiggie Did uninstall of VLC & Spotify. Still same.

Comment: Latest Update: Updated to MacOS Sonoma, still the problem exists

Comment: What apps were you using when you tested the behaviour after uninstalling VLC & Spotify?

Comment: @benwiggy Google Chrome